# Multiple deletion & edit of data in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I was trying to delete one data from the database but it would either delete the whole data in the database; it also the same problem for edit.

this code is for delete a user that will show a prompt when deleting a user:

```
<div id="delete_user<?php echo $id; ?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">Are you Sure yuo want to Delete this Data?</div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete_user.php<?php echo '?id='.$id; ?>"><i class="icon-check"></i>&nbsp;Yes</a>
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-remove icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this code here below is the actual delete from the database

```
<?php
include('dbcon.php');

$id=$_GET['id'];

mysql_query("delete from users where user_id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());

header('location:users.php');
?>
```

Comment: You mean deleting all rows of the table?

Comment: ahh yeah sorry about that..

Comment: did u check value is set of not in $_GET['id']

Comment: You're a sitting duck for SQL Injection attacks, as the user submitted data isn't even escaped. As mentioned in one of the answers below, the user submitted can be quickly validated by type casting ID as an integer Anything that "fails" the typecasting will get returned as 0 and it's very unlikely that there will be a user with an ID of 0. Also are you aware that the mysql_* extension that you've used was removed in version 7 of PHP. You should now be using PDO and using prepared statements when sending validated, user submitted data to the database

Comment: @Chouny, are you getting value of `$id=$_GET['id'];` in **delete_user.php page** also try to echo your query and run it in phpmyadmin

Comment: @AmitRajput @Ms.Nehal; thanks for the answer helped alot

Answer (score 0):

First check if value is set in `$_GET['id']` then perform your action.

```
<?php
include('dbcon.php');

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    mysql_query("delete from users where user_id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
}

header('location:users.php');
?>
```

Comment: `isset` checks whether variable exists or not not checks for values here you should check for value too;

Comment: Why you added `'$id'` single quote for integer value?

Answer (score -1):

your code seem to be okay, just check the debug the id value.

But still i strongly believe for such action don't pass id's in GET method. Use POST in ajax.

Below is the code with the ajax using POST method to pass the id to delete_user.php page

```
<div id="delete_user<?php echo $id; ?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="alert alert-danger">Are you Sure yuo want to Delete this Data?</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteUser(<?php echo $id; ?>)" href="javascript:void(0)">  <i class="icon-check"></i>&nbsp;Yes</a>
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-remove icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Close</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Below the jquery ajax part

```
function deletUser(id) {
$.ajax({
  url: 'delete_user.php',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {"id" : id},
  success: function(data) {
    // on success alter the div structure.....
  }
});
}
```

below is code for your delete_user.php page

```
include('dbcon.php');
if(isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] != ''){
$id = (int)$_POST['id'];
mysql_query("delete from users where user_id=$id") or die(mysql_error());
}
header('location:users.php');
```

Comment: Sending post request and trying to get data as get request `$id = (int)$_GET['id'];` what is this?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 That's my mistake i have just forgot to change the GET with POST. Please ignore that part

Comment: Why you added `'$id'` single quote for integer value?

Comment: One more mistake php will parse the variable if its in between double quote.

Comment: I would suggest to use PDO to prevent the sql injection. here I have just show the use of ajax to work with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107851/discussion-between-user2314870-and-itzmukeshy7).